# How to use multiple colors with geom_image()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggimage

I'm having trouble figuring out how to highlight multiple colors with `ggimage`.

It's clear how one can set different images to **a single** color  ([from vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggimage/vignettes/ggimage.html)):

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")

set.seed(2017-02-21)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                y = rnorm(10),
                z = sample(c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A")),
                image = sample(c("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png",
                                 "https://jeroenooms.github.io/images/frink.png"),
                               size=10, replace = TRUE)
                )

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image), color="firebrick")
```

I introduced another column `z` into the example because the dataset I'm working with has a variable I would like apply the `color` aesthetic on.

I tried how one would typically set it in `ggplot()` (and/or `geom_point()`) call but I don't get my desired output:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image), color=d$z) 

Error in col2rgb(color) : invalid color name 'test'
```

It doesn't accept multiple colors?

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image), color = c("blue","red","green"))
```

I also tried to specify three colors with `RColorBrewer`:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

my_color <- brewer.pal(3, "Set1")
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image), color = my_color)
```

I would really appreciate your help trying to solve this.

Comment: Are you after `ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image, color = z))`?

Comment: if i'm reading geom_image correctly (https://github.com/cran/ggimage/blob/master/R/geom_image.R) the routine does not support color as an aesthetic so the color param outside of aes applies one color as you've shown. Typically a geom would use your z column inside aes to apply different colors but this doesn't look like it's available for geom_image. A possible alternative would be to draw a circle or rectangle behind the image with your color value (perhaps by calling geom_point before calling geom_image)

Comment: I tried looking at the source code too (with `edit(getAnywhere('geom_image'))`) but I couldn't make too much sense of the code. Thanks for clearing this up, I'll open an issue on the Github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    set.seed(2017-02-21)
    d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                y = rnorm(10),
                z = sample(c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A")),
                image = sample(c("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png",
                                 "https://jeroenooms.github.io/images/frink.png"),
                               size=10, replace = TRUE)
)
    ggplot(d, aes(x, y,group=z)) + geom_image(aes(image=image,color=factor(z)))
```

Comment: 3 years + 4 months - "Better late than never" 

Thanks for the answer :)

Once you've passed factor(z) to the color param you can customize your colors via the categories (here A,B + C)




ggplot(d, aes(x, y,group=z)) + geom_image(aes(image=image,color=factor(z))) + scale_color_manual(values = c("C" = "green", "A" = "pink", "B" = "orange"))